# Heroku copiar variable a otra variable

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, heroku, environment

Tengo las siguientes variables en mi .env en local:

```
MIX_APP_URL=http://localhost
MIX_TEST_1=${MIX_APP_URL}
MIX_TEST_2="${MIX_APP_URL}"
MIX_TEST_3=$MIX_APP_URL
```

Esto me da como resultado (es el resultado que espero en mi deploy):

[image: 1]

En mi despliegue en Heroku tengo las siguientes:

[image: 2]

Cuando ejecuto el comando `heroku config` obtengo las siguientes variables:

[image: 3]

Y en el deploy obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: 4]

Comment: ya compilaste el webpack?

Comment: @NicolasAldana claro

Comment: no te llega el valor al js de las variables, obviamente heroku solo te va entregar el contenido del archivo .env, el prefijo MIX es una extensión de dotenv js y es laravelmix quien reemplaza ese valor en la construcción de los resources, heroku ni laravel van hacer ese map